# To handle the null pointer exception

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

while updating the two dates it is updated , while inserting the date it shows the null pointer exception the error is
**Production_date: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.Production_date: line 51, column 1**

My code is

```
trigger Production_date on Opportunity (after Insert,after update) 
{
    Set<Id> pbeIds = new Set<Id>();
    
        if(trigger.isInsert )
        {
            for(Opportunity opli : Trigger.new) 
            {
                pbeIds.add(opli.Id);
             
            }
        }
    if(trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            for (Opportunity opli1 : Trigger.old) 
            {
                if(opli1.Id != null )
                {
                    pbeIds.add(opli1.Id);
         
                }
            }
        
     List <Opportunity> opp = [SELECT id , Production_Date__c,
                                       (SELECT id, ServiceDate,Product2Id 
                                        FROM OpportunityLineItems)
                                        FROM Opportunity 
                                        WHERE id in :pbeIds];
      List<Product2> prd = [SELECT id
                           FROM Product2]; 
                           
      OpportunityLineItem[] opportunityupdates = new OpportunityLineItem[] {};
   
       for(Opportunity oppr: opp)
        {
           for(OpportunityLineItem o:oppr.OpportunityLineItems)
           {  
               for(Product2 p :prd)
                {
                     if(p.id == o.Product2Id)
                     {
                     
                        if(o.ServiceDate != null && oppr.Production_Date__c != null)
                            {
                            date addedservicedate2 ;                    
                            Date oldOppr = Trigger.oldMap.get(oppr.Id).Production_Date__c;
                            system.debug('oldOppr===='+oldOppr);
                            Date newOppr = oppr.Production_Date__c;
                            system.debug('newOppr===='+newOppr);
                           
                                Integer noOfDays =  oldOppr.daysBetween(newOppr);
                                system.debug('noOfDays===='+noOfDays);
                                system.debug('ServiceDate===='+o.ServiceDate);
                                addedservicedate2 = o.ServiceDate+(noOfDays);
                           
                          
                         
                                o.ServiceDate = addedservicedate2;
                                opportunityupdates.add(o);
                              
                            
                        }
                    }
                     
                }
                  
            }    
        }
       
        update opportunityupdates;
    }             
}
```

Comment: Please stop adding irrelevant tags to your questions. This question appears to have nothing to do with salesforceDX or communities.

Answer (score 1):

If Line 51 is indeed

```
Integer noOfDays =  oldOppr.daysBetween(newOppr);
```

the problem should be pretty clear from the debug logs you already have in place:

```
system.debug('oldOppr===='+oldOppr);
system.debug('newOppr===='+newOppr);
```

That should immediately show you where you have a `null` value that you need to write appropriate business logic to deal with.

---

You really need to pay attention to the efficiency problems that have been raised multiple times in past questions about your trigger code.

If you deploy this code to production and you have any significant number of Products, or update multiple records in a transaction, you are likely to hit CPU time exceptions. You need to use Maps instead of a nested `for` loop.

*Edit*: While the above is true in general principle, on a re-read I noticed that your innermost `for` loop *actually does nothing at all*, because you never use the loop variable. You should delete it entirely.

Comment: ok , thanks for your reply